# AWS CLI on instance with ECR IAM Policy Set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

i have an IAM role that i have tested with the simulator to provide AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly access. I have launched an ec2 with the role, and i can see in the EC2 console that it is attached to the instance. When i SSH into the EC2, and attempt to run

*aws ecr get-authorization-token*

I get the message 
*'AccessKeyId'*

I have attempted to do "aws configure" and set the default region and output (leaving the ACCESS and SECRET empty) but still get the same result...

Can anyone help with this please?

[Screenshot of 'error'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qhHw.png)

DEBUG -

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-101-105 ~]$ aws ecr get-authorization-token

'AccessKeyId'
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-101-105 ~]$ aws ecr get-authorization-token --debug
2017-02-01 15:03:00,704 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.11.44 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.41-36.55.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.5.7
2017-02-01 15:03:00,704 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['ecr', 'get-authorization-token', '--debug']
2017-02-01 15:03:00,704 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x7efd7abe4578>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,704 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x7efd7b516c80>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,705 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ecr/2015-09-21/service-2.json
2017-02-01 15:03:00,712 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.ecr: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x7efd7be11488>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,712 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: ecr
2017-02-01 15:03:00,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecr: calling handler <function _inject_get_login at 0x7efd7acff1b8>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,713 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ecr: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7efd7abe8938>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,716 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'registry-ids', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7efd7a87d9d0>)])
2017-02-01 15:03:00,716 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x7efd7abe4b90>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,716 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x7efd7b520b90>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,717 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x7efd7ac735f0>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,719 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/ecr/2015-09-21/paginators-1.json
2017-02-01 15:03:00,719 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x7efd7ac5d9b0>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,719 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7efd7a87da10>>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,719 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7efd7a85a750>>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,720 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecr.get-authorization-token.registry-ids: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7efd7b53aaa0>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,720 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecr.get-authorization-token.cli-input-json: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7efd7b53aaa0>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,720 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ecr.get-authorization-token.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7efd7b53aaa0>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7efd7a85a750>>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.ecr.get-authorization-token: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7efd7a87da10>>
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2017-02-01 15:03:00,721 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: config-file
2017-02-01 15:03:00,722 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: ec2-credentials-file
2017-02-01 15:03:00,722 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: boto-config
2017-02-01 15:03:00,722 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: container-role
2017-02-01 15:03:00,722 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: iam-role
2017-02-01 15:03:00,725 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
2017-02-01 15:03:00,726 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11
2017-02-01 15:03:00,727 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254
2017-02-01 15:03:00,728 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/jenkins-DEV HTTP/1.1" 200 255
2017-02-01 15:03:00,729 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 197, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 333, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 503, in __call__
    call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 620, in invoke
    verify=parsed_globals.verify_ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 825, in create_client
    credentials = self.get_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 449, in get_credentials
    'credential_provider').load_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 1083, in load_credentials
    creds = provider.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 488, in load
    metadata = fetcher.retrieve_iam_role_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 203, in retrieve_iam_role_credentials
    'access_key': data[role_name]['AccessKeyId'],
KeyError: 'AccessKeyId'
2017-02-01 15:03:00,735 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

'AccessKeyId'
```

EDIT:

Found that the trust policy was set up incorrectly..

Comment: That's an odd error.  Could you try running the command with the ``--debug`` option and post the results?

Comment: thanks, added to main post.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for posterity sake so others can see what to do if they hit this error.  An EC2 instance profile (an IAM role) needs to allow the EC2 service to assume the role, so you'll need a trust policy like this one:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```